# SQL select query not as intended

Tags: sql

I want to select the rows that column a is the same, but column b has different values (while removing duplicates in column b, so only one row represent the rows that have the same value in column b)

Table:

```
a   b
--  --
1   111
1   111
1   222
1   333
1   222

2   523
5   323
```

I tried this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY b HAVING a = 1;
```

which returns what i want with current inputs:

**output**

```
1 111
1 222
1 333
```

however if the result is one row, nothing is selected.
for example:

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY b HAVING a = 2;
```

doesn't return anything, and I want it to return one row.

```
2 523
```

what is the problem with the query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like all you really need is `distinct`, eg

```
select distinct a, b
from t
where a=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is invalid in most databases because you are using a non-aggregated value in the `HAVING` clause.

Instead, you should check if each group contains only 1 distinct vale:

```
SELECT MAX(a) a, b 
FROM tablename 
GROUP BY b 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a) = 1 AND MAX(a) = ?;
```

Replace `?` with the value that you search for.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5381dfb5086430fc0ccb1e9f13f22946).